# email format not consistent with visualforce email template

Tags: email-template

i'm using visualforce email templates to receive mail but seems the format is not the same as in template when the mail is recieved, used both style and inline style but seems not to work:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Your campaign {!relatedTo.Name} is due to start" recipientType="User"             relatedToType="Campaign" rendered="true">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <head>
    <style>
    #header {
        position: relative;
        background-color:white;
        left: 100px;
        width:60%;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        padding:5px; 
    }
    #body {
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;
        background-color:white;
        height:250px;
        width:60%;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;          
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#00A1C1">
        <div>
            <div id ="header">
                <img src="url" alt="logo"></img>
            </div>
            <div id ="ibody" style="position: relative;left: 100px;background-color:white; height:250px; width:60%;             float:left; padding:5px;">
            Dear {!recipient.name}

            <br></br> 
            <br>
                Notification that "{!relatedTo.Name}" is due to start today.
            </br>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

i'm using apex class to send the email in background....any inputs to fix this please?

APEX Class:

```
            //@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
        public class CampaignMailOnStartDate implements Schedulable{
            public static void getStartdateToday(List<Campaign> campaign){
                String objectName = 'Campaign';
                String query = 'SELECT';
                
              //Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
                Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Campaign.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
                for (SObjectField fld : objectFields.values()) {
                    string fld_str = string.valueOf(fld);
                    query += ' ' + fld + ', ';
                    /*if (fld_str == 'id'         || fld_str == 'name'      || fld_str == 'parentid'    ||
                        fld_str == 'status'      || fld_str == 'startdate' || fld_str == 'enddate'     ||
                        fld_str == 'description' || fld_str == 'ownerid'   || fld_str == 'createddate' ||
                        fld_str == 'createdbyid')
                    query += ' ' + fld + ', ';*/
                }
                // Strip off the last comma if it exists.
                if (query.subString(query.Length()-2,query.Length()) == ', '){
                    query = query.subString(0,query.Length()-2);
                }
                
                // Add FROM statement
                query += ' FROM ' + objectName;
                query += ' WHERE StartDate = TODAY'; 
                 
                try {  
                        List<Campaign> campaignList = new List<Campaign>();
                      campaignList = database.query(query);
                        for(Campaign c : campaignList){
                        campaign.add(c);
                      }
                  } catch (QueryException e){
                        //perform exception handling
                        system.debug('Error in Query');
                  }  
             }
            
            public static void sendMail(List<Campaign> Campaigns, EmailTemplate template ){
                List< Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List< Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                for(Campaign camp:campaigns){
                    //New instance of a single email message
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    // Set mail template
                    mail.setTemplateId(template.Id);
                    // Set target id
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(camp.CreatedById);
                    // Set mail body
                    String htmlBody = template.HtmlValue; 
                    User createdBy = [select name from user where id =: camp.CreatedById limit 1]; 
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Campaign.CreatedBy}', createdBy.Name);
                htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Campaign.Name}', camp.Name);
                    //mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
                    system.debug('User Id -> '+ camp.CreatedById + 'Campaign Id -> '+ camp.Id);
                    mail.setWhatId(camp.Id);
                    mail.setBccSender(false);
                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    emails.add( mail );
                    //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
               }
                Messaging.sendEmail( emails );
            }
            
           public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
                List<Campaign> campaign = new List<Campaign>();
                getStartdateToday(campaign);
                for(Campaign camp:campaign){
                system.debug('Campaign -> ' + camp.Name);}
                //EmailTemplate template = [select Subject, HtmlValue, Body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Campaign_Due' Limit 1];
                EmailTemplate template = [select Subject, HtmlValue, Body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'CampaignDueToStart' Limit 1];
                if (template.Id != null){
                system.debug('Template Id -> ' + template.Id);
                sendMail(campaign, template);            
                }
                else
                system.debug('Template not found');
            }
         }
```

Comment: Can you share apex class as well ?

Comment: When you say the format is not the same, have you used the preview tool on the Email Template detail page? Does the format there differ from what you expect based on your code, or is it the case that the email client (gmail, outlook, etc.) is displaying the email differently than the Salesforce Preview?

Comment: @D.S. - I've seen this -- SFDC preview rendering doesn't agree with Yahoo mail rendering

Comment: Preview is working fine but when the email arrives in ms outlook the format, for instance the width and height is not the same as in the preview.....

Comment: Unfortunately this is the nature of email clients. They are all different and some are more opinionated about how they will display email content. There is a handy chart at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ that might provide you some help on what css is most likely to display the way you want.